# Pain of configuring various environments in development and production (Rails 4 application)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, configuration, environment-variables, conventions

As per best practices, my development team does not store the application config file in a repo for security reasons (we use a `config/application.yml` file to store configs).  However, when we actually develop and deploy, this causes some problems:

1. A developer needs to add a new external URL that is different depending on what environment the application is running in.  Since there is no config file in the repo, he cannot update a single file that gets synced when another developer pulls the code.  To make this happen, he updates his local `config/application.yml` file and then each other developer updates their local file, and then we have to add the new ENV variable to the server's `config/application.yml`.  Has to be a better solution.
2. If we stored the `config/application.yml` file in the repo and shared it among everyone and the servers, this solves the problem of sharing/updating global configs, BUT it opens up the possibility that a developer may accidentally start their local application in production mode and touch live data or spam real users with test emails (has happened which is why it's a concern).

Is there a standard best practice for solving these types of problems?  It seems I either sacrifice productivity for security but can't really have both.

I've been thinking about creating a `config/development.yml` file in the repo that all developers share, which stores all environments EXCEPT production.  That way they can share config/ENV items for development and sync them up.  But in production, I would have a `config/production.yml` file that ONLY lives on the servers.

If the application is started in anything except production environment, it loads the `development.yml` file.  If it is started in production, it loads the `production.yml` file.  But since the `production.yml` file does NOT live in the repo (only on the servers), there's no chance that a developer can accidentally touch live data or spam real users, etc...

Have any professional developers tried a scheme like this?  I've done a lot of googling but really haven't found a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [RailsConfig](https://github.com/railsconfig/rails_config) gem. This allows you do to exactly what you stated, but with the ease of a gem. This also allows you and your dev team to have local yaml files that override settings.

```
config/settings.yml
config/settings/#{environment}.yml
config/environments/#{environment}.yml

config/settings.local.yml
config/settings/#{environment}.local.yml
config/environments/#{environment}.local.yml
```

You would then just have `config/settings/production.yml` within your `.gitignore` so that it will not be checked into source control.